# Mint 18.2, Cinnamon, NVIDIA Quadro M1200, nvidia-375 driver, nomodeset

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, nomodeset

I just got a Dell Precision 7520 which comes with Ubuntu 16.04 and the NVIDIA Quadro M1200 GPU. I installed Linux Mint 18.2 and then the nvidia-375 apt package. After reboot I hear the Mint jingle and the screen is blank. From my research this seems to have something to do with `nomodeset`, however during boot holding down Shift does not bring up any menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I've spent the last year trying to install either Ubuntu Cinnamon or Linux Mint with Cinnamon. I've tried and returned close to a dozen laptops. The only laptop that worked was a System76 with a GTX1060. But I didn't need a gaming laptop plus it was eating way too much of my battery life.

I've had many Desktop Linux machines with no problems. But it seems like all laptop refuse to run Cinnamon and OpenGL correctly.

I finally got an answer from nVidia technical support: "On laptops if your laptop is Optimus based (Optimus means it has both Intel and NVIDIA graphics and switches between them automatically), unfortunately it won't consistently work with the NVIDIA driver as a display device unless there is a way to disable Optimus or a way to disable the onboard Intel graphics card, usually in system bios."

You can check if it is Optimus based by running lspci -nn. If you see two VGA devices (one NVIDIA, one Intel) then it is an Optimus system. Luckily, the Dell BIOS allows for me turn off Optimus switching and disable the built in Intel Graphics option. I was finally able to install Linux Mint with Cinnamon and run my OpenGL programs correctly.